# Finding unknowns in function from known output using Scipy/Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following python function required inputs a and b.

```
def interimfunc(x,y,z):
    #this is a dummy function - not a part of the actual question but included for completeness.
    #the actual function involves some statistical treatment - but that is not a problem here.
    sol = x*y+z
    return sol


def finalfunc(a, b):
    interimsol1 = interimfunc(0.4,a,b)
    interimsol2 = interimfunc(0.8,a,b)
    finalsol = interimsol1/interimsol2
    return finalsol
```

if `finalsol` is a known value.
How do I find out the unknowns "a" and "b" by solving non-linear system of equations??

===

I got 4 down-votes after posting this. I am a mechanical engineer and learning computer science. I did try researching on the internet but need to refine my search - hence I asked a question to experts here.

===

In addition to above equations - there is one more information:

```
interimsol2 = interimfunc(0.8,a,b)
```

where    `interimsol2 = 10 #i.e. known value`
How do we inclde this new information in our unknown finding?

===

Actual problem as requested below by @SergeyIvanov

```
def func(mu, sigma):
    tenpercent = st.norm.ppf(2, mu, sigma)
    ninetypercent = st.norm.ppf(2, mu, sigma)
    rfs = tenpercent/ninetypercent
    return rfs
```

Comment: you have to do some reading first. `a, b` are parameters of function `finalfunc`. You have to provide them when you call the function for it to be able to calculate and return the output, `finalsol`. If you want to *reverse* the process and go from `finalsol` to `a` and `b`, you have to do the math first.

Comment: seems to me that `finalsol` will always be `0.5` regardless of what `a` and `b` you provide. and i am not a mathematician.. That means that the function yielding them is not *reversable*. so you can't. if you simplify it, it boils down to `finalsol=0.4*a*b/(0.8*a*b)` which is `finalsol=0.4/0.8=0.5`

Comment: In your current code, the finalSol value = 0.5?

Comment: You should solve equation finalfunc(a, b) == known_solution, but it is impossibe with two unkown variables

Comment: @SergeyIvanov i tried looping `a` and `b` in a for loop. but that is very inefficient.

Comment: You need one more solution. This leads to system of equations (nonlinear), or fix one of the variable (a or b)

Comment: It seems you need this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Yes Sir (for the nonlinear system of equations part) and No Sir (for fix one variable) :) ! We have two unknowns and 3 equations - i think we can solve this. Just want to know how. MathCad does this using "find" command. Need to find the Scipy equivalent of it.

Comment: Do you really need 3 equations for two unknowns? Two equations is enough. Or you you have Overdetermined system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system)?

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Sir - I know my problem is genuine. It is being solved in MathCad - I need it in python because we need to do it on a larger scale. I do not agree about the "Overdetermined system" thinking. Actually - its just 2 equations and 2 unknowns in this case if you see.

Comment: Please change initial problem from _"finalsol" should be equal to a particular value_ to _"finalsol" should be equal to a set of particular values_  (or something like that for correctness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should solve a system of nonlinear equations. This code should solve your problem in case of two equations for two known solutions (of course you can extend it):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

known_values = [3,5]

def interimfunc(x,y,z):
    sol = x*y+z
    return sol

def finalfunc(a, b):
    interimsol1 = interimfunc(0.4,a,b)
    interimsol2 = interimfunc(0.8,a,b)
    finalsol = interimsol1/interimsol2
    return finalsol

def equations(p):
    a, b = p
    return (finalfunc(a,b) - known_values[0], # finalfunc(a,b) == solution1
            finalfunc(a,b) - known_values[1]) # finalfunc(a,b) == solution2

a, b =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))# solution
print(a,b)
# -6192.07497308 5779.26987919

print(equations((a, b)))
# (1.0000003476651482, -0.99999965233485177) <-- bad convergence beacause there is no free paremeter in finalfunc.
```

But it works only with equal known_values, that is pointless (solution will be a random combination of a and b). The problem is that you should have something to distinguish two equations finalfunc (e.g. additional parameter), because you can get diffrent solutions only with different arguments. So finally you should have something like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def interimfunc(x,y,z):
    sol = x*y+z
    return sol

def finalfunc(a, b, c ):
    interimsol1 = interimfunc(0.4,a,b) + c
    interimsol2 = interimfunc(0.8,a,b) + c
    finalsol = interimsol1/interimsol2
    return finalsol


known_values = [0.8260869565217391,0.8333333333333334]


def equations(p):
    a, b = p
    return (finalfunc(a,b,0) - known_values[0], # finalfunc(a,b,c) == solution1
            finalfunc(a,b,1) - known_values[1]) # finalfunc(a,b,c) == solution2


a, b =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))# solution
print(a,b)
print(equations((a, b)))
# 10.0 15.0 <-- correct values
# (4.4408920985006262e-16, 2.2204460492503131e-16) <-- good convergence
```

For last example:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import scipy.stats as st

def equations(p):
    mu, sigma = p
    tenpercent = st.norm.ppf(2, mu, sigma)
    ninetypercent = st.norm.ppf(2, mu, sigma)
    return (ninetypercent - 500,
            tenpercent / ninetypercent - 1.0)

mu, sigma =  fsolve(equations,x0=(100, 10))# solution
print("mu, sigma:",mu, sigma)
print(equations((mu, sigma)))
```

The problem here is that `ppf` can generate `nan` and ruin an optimization process. So guess values should be proposed very carefully.

Comment: What is the value of `finalsol` we are assuming in the second solution?

Comment: I solved it myself and got `0.8260869565217391` for `0` and and `0.8333` for `1`. but the value changes for `2`...We have to relook how to solve this. Meanwhile - this is what is being done on MathCad: http://engr.bd.psu.edu/forsman/metbd_050/Assignments/Mathcad%20-%20Explanation_of_Find.pdf

Comment: I used the first solution - but it needs a very good guess in place of `(1,1)` in the line
`a, b =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))# solution`
Another observation is - it gives multiple close solutions to the problem and not the exact answer.

Comment: I explained why first solution is not incorrect (technically yes, but actually no). If you have different values for the same arguments you should use nonlinear least squares fitting. It is another story.

Comment: ..or you should use different functions in `def equations` with the same arguments (a,b). This is what you show in MathCad examples.

Comment: That is what we are doing right?
`interimfunc(0.4,a,b)` and `interimfunc(0.8,a,b)` are two different functions using same arguments? This problem can also be solved using Excel Solve or GoalSeek. Infact - what is the **Scipy** _equivalent_ of **Excel Solver**?

Comment: I get what I want with first solution and using broyden2.
But I have to use `broyden2(equations1, (1000,500))` to get correct decimal location of the solution. 
For Example:
for `(100,50)` start guess - the solver yields `50.0` and `6.0` but correct answer is `500` and `60` after using start guess of `(1000,500)`. how to solve this

Comment: In your example 0.4 and 0.5 are just constants inside one function. What you say would be true if `interimfunc(0.4,a,b) == value1` and `interimfunc(0.8,a,b)==value2`

Comment: you are right about value1 and value2. I have updated the question - value2 is a known value. how to include this in the unknown solving?
And we always knew that value1/value2 == known_value.

Comment: Concerning the method I don't see a reason to use broyden2 instead of fsolve. To my mind, fsolve is more stable.

Comment: Please ask additional questions via email (sergei.v.ivanov at google mail)